# What is the best web server for Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver

What is the best web server for ruby on rails application? Why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) running on Apache. Easy to set up, low memory usage, and well supported.

Comment: what about lighttpd did you chick it?

Comment: lighttpd has myriad problems, I wouldn't recommend it under any circumstances.

Comment: The free version isn't as good as I had hoped. Both [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) and [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) seem to offer better handling of concurrency and slow client handling.

Answer (score 35):

Both GitHub and 37 Signals use nginx + unicorn.

https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn

Comment: Yes I also use the same combination with linode VPS, very neat.

Answer (score 5):

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is becoming the norm. It has more configuration options and [is faster](http://izumi.plan99.net/blog/index.php/2008/03/31/benchmark-passenger-mod_rails-vs-mongrel-vs-thin/).

Comment: "It has more ..." than what?

Answer (score 5):

Additionally, for something very quick/easy on dev, try http://pow.cx/

Comment: Yeah I use it. very neat! :-)